# How to sample a list of doubles in c#

Tags: c#, math, sampling

Suppose I have a list of double values in C# that contains a pair of double values that looks like this:

```
var ListToSample = new List<double>
{ 49.5353, 49.6241, 49.92432 };
```

And from these values I want to create a 100 samples. What is the most effective way of doing that.

Comment: How would you get the 100 samples? By duplicating the values?

Comment: Or by randomizing it?

Comment: Use List<PointF> class which contains a list of x,y values.

Comment: Would the result be a list of 100 doubles?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Enumerable.Repeat`:

```
var hundredSamples = Enumerable.Repeat(ListToSample, 100);
var allLists = new List<List<Double>>(100);
allLists.AddRange(hundredSamples);
```

or in one line:

```
var allLists = Enumerable.Repeat(ListToSample, 100).ToList();
```